# Autoprefixer not adding grid prefixes for IE

Tags: webpack, vue.js, postcss, autoprefixer, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli version 3.x.

I've added a vue.config.js file:

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const plugin = autoprefixer({ grid: true });
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    //get the index of the scss rule
    let index = config.module.rules.findIndex(item => item.test.test("*.scss"));
    const rule = config.module.rules[index];
    //get the index of the postcss-loader config
    let postCssIdx = rule.use.findIndex(
      item => item.loader === "postcss-loader"
    );

    //add the autoprefixer plugin
    config.module.rules[index].use[postCssIdx].options = {
      ...rule.use[postCssIdx].options,
      plugins: [plugin]
    };
  }
};
```

But although I've set `grid:true` in the options, the grid attributes are not prefixed.

What am i missing?

Comment: whats  the autoprefixer version; do you specify a custom [browserlist](http://browserl.ist/) ?

Comment: `"autoprefixer": "^8.2.0"` and i have browserlist defined in package.json: `"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]`

Comment: there is currently an [autoprefixer#954](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/954) issue regarding grid prefixes in media queries - would that apply to your usecase ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't use media queries. Also i have it running in a different project using gulp, and it works perfect. I'm guessing it's a vue-cli/webpack issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it, The rule i extended is the rule for external scss files, but it does not apply to styles in .vue files.

So i needed to update the vue-loader configuration and add autoprefixer there:

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const plugin = autoprefixer({ grid: true });
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    //1. Define autoprefixer for external scss
    //get the index of the scss rule
    let index = config.module.rules.findIndex(item => item.test.test("*.scss"));
    let rule = config.module.rules[index];
    //get the index of the postcss-loader config
    let postCssIdx = rule.use.findIndex(
      item => item.loader === "postcss-loader"
    );

    const postcssOptions = rule.use[postCssIdx].options;

    //add the autoprefixer plugin
    config.module.rules[index].use[postCssIdx].options = {
      ...postcssOptions,
      plugins: [plugin]
    };

    //2. Define autoprefixer for vue files
    index = config.module.rules.findIndex(item => item.test.test("*.vue"));
    rule = config.module.rules[index];
    rule.use[0].options = {
      ...rule.use[0].options,
      postcss: {
        plugins: [plugin]
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: So what file was this put into? webpack.config.js??

Comment: the file is vue.config.js